# Native crash at app start occasionally on Android 5

Tags: android

I am starting my app on startup with help of BootReceiver provided by Android O.S

Sometimes though, my app crashes and prints output below:

```
F/libc    ( 1309): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x12528a20 in tid 1309 (.com.attendance)
I/DEBUG   (  181): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  181): Build fingerprint: 'Allwinner/astar_98v/astar-98v:5.1.1/LMY47V/20151104:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  181): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  181): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   (  181): pid: 1309, tid: 1309, name: .com.attendance  >>> sparkgoattendance.bsobe.com.attendance <<<
I/DEBUG   (  181): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x12528a20
I/DEBUG   (  181):     r0 12c1a400  r1 00000000  r2 00000011  r3 12528a00
I/DEBUG   (  181):     r4 b6e47df4  r5 a4817391  r6 00000000  r7 12c1a400
I/DEBUG   (  181):     r8 b47bfa40  r9 a4817391  sl 37729a5d  fp 000001f5
I/DEBUG   (  181):     ip 37729a5d  sp beb4f3a8  lr b45ceff7  pc b45cc19a  cpsr 000d0030
I/DEBUG   (  181): 
I/DEBUG   (  181): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #00 pc 000bf19a  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::Class::GetDexFile()+1)
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #01 pc 000c1ff3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::Class::DescriptorEquals(char const*)+186)
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #02 pc 000c3379  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::LookupClassFromTableLocked(char const*, art::mirror::ClassLoader*, unsigned int)+240)
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #03 pc 000c7cb1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::LookupClass(char const*, unsigned int, art::mirror::ClassLoader*)+48)
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #04 pc 000d614f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE.part.415+54)
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #05 pc 000d7c25  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::ResolveType(art::DexFile const&, unsigned short, art::Handle<art::mirror::DexCache>, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>)+132)
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #06 pc 000d8b3f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::ResolveMethod(art::DexFile const&, unsigned int, art::Handle<art::mirror::DexCache>, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, art::Handle<art::mirror::ArtMethod>, art::InvokeType)+90)
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #07 pc 00265f47  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::ResolveMethod(art::Thread*, unsigned int, art::mirror::ArtMethod**, art::InvokeType)+142)
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #08 pc 0027f5e5  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickResolutionTrampoline+2704)
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #09 pc 000a2b7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_resolution_trampoline+10)
I/DEBUG   (  181):     #10 pc 00000000  <unknown>
W/ProcessCpuTracker(  490): Skipping unknown process pid 1456
W/ActivityManager(  490):   Force finishing activity 1 sparkgoattendance.bsobe.com.attendance/.MainActivity
I/WindowManager(  490): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{3cc1ba32 ActivityRecord{14f4023d u0 sparkgoattendance.bsobe.com.attendance/.MainActivity t30 f}} appWin=Window{29cc352c u0 Starting sparkgoattendance.bsobe.com.attendance} drawState=4
W/ActivityManager(  490): Exception thrown during pause
W/ActivityManager(  490): android.os.DeadObjectException
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:704)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:828)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2777)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2634)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2501)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11521)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11418)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12102)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11613)
W/ActivityManager(  490):   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
I/ActivityManager(  490): Process sparkgoattendance.bsobe.com.attendance (pid 1309) has died
W/WindowManager(  490): Failed looking up window
W/WindowManager(  490): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3a404df does not exist
W/WindowManager(  490):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8568)
W/WindowManager(  490):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8559)
W/WindowManager(  490):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2598)
W/WindowManager(  490):     at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:187)
W/WindowManager(  490):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3052)
W/WindowManager(  490):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5539)
W/WindowManager(  490):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3358)
W/WindowManager(  490):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/WindowManager(  490):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
W/WindowManager(  490):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/WindowManager(  490):     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

I am updating my app via root permissions, for that I have another background service, which downloads new apk file, deletes old app then installs new app. I am thinking that maybe this way of installation might not be doing some things that a normal installation should take care of.

For installation process I am using 'pm' command in Android and installation process doesn't print any error messages whatsoever.

Comment: This may be caused by calling a system API that is not available on your target device. (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl does not exist).  In Settings > Developer Options, there is a check box called "Don't keep activities" "Destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it". The box may be checked.  just unchecked it.

Comment: @JonGoodwin Hmm, I am confused about it being not available sometimes, while most of the time it works without crash. Is it about the time, is app trying to call it so early sometimes that causes to crash ?

Comment: I looked up on it, it is not checked

Comment: "Exception thrown during pause" check your tidy in your OnPause of "sparkgoattendance.bsobe.com.attendance/.MainActivity" (post some code we can work with). Minimal code example that shows the error.